# Bootstrap Order Of Image, Title & Description for Mobile vs Desktop

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap layout for my page on mobile that looks like this:

`[Title]
 [Image]
 [Description]`

On desktop I would like it to appear as so:

`[Image][Title]
 [Image][Description]`

Whereby the single image from mobile takes up the left side of the screen and the title & description stack on top of each other on the right side. If the ordering was not changing here I would be able to do it but I cannot think how to have the title & description stack on top of each. My current layout pushes the description onto a new line instead. How do you create this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution : -

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://alto-live.s3.amazonaws.com/C39a2mvdXkhEsdxtqRWs55o4xGM/xw37B9xnyd1qi8ARMKz2jR_-A18/Photo/[2]/CRgx69es5Eeqfb2A35bWbg.jpg" alt="your image">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3 class="text-center">Image Title</h3>
        <p class="text-center">Image desciption</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: With this layout - on mobile the title goes below the image. Is it possible to have this go above the image on mobile?

Comment: YEah!! Use pull classes of bootstrap... Checkout here https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_helpers.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `media queries` and `order`:

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 0 40px;
}

.container:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.container img {
  width: 200px;
}

.container .image {
  float: left;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
  }

  .container .image {
    order: 2;
  }

  .container .title {
    order: 1;
  }

  .container .description {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTmzMFjujgib4Md4MHoGD4VoIDwqjaG3DDrylUns_rY8dgSuybA" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="title">title</div>
  <div class="description">description</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution using bootstrap : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4suf47q/1/)

```
<div class="row">
<div id="title" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-push-4">
  TITLE
</div>
<div id="image" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">
  IMAGE
</div>
<div id="desc" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
  Description
</div>
```

```
#title{
  background-color: #cd4578;
  height:30px;
}
#image{
  background-color: #666;
  height:60px;
}
#desc{
  background-color: #87de65;
  height:30px;
}
@media (min-width:768px) {
  #desc {
    margin-top:-30px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can keep one div only visible in mobile, here's the code:

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">
        <h3 class="text-center">Image Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://alto-live.s3.amazonaws.com/C39a2mvdXkhEsdxtqRWs55o4xGM/xw37B9xnyd1qi8ARMKz2jR_-A18/Photo/[2]/CRgx69es5Eeqfb2A35bWbg.jpg"
            alt="your image">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h3 class="text-center hidden-xs">Image Title</h3>
        <p class="text-center">Image desciption</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

class 'visible-xs' will make div visible in only in mobile, and class 'hidden-xs' will make the h3 only hidden in mobile.